# Is zu correct in this context?

Tags: preposition

A Slow German episode contains the following sentence:

> Dabei sollte man die Fahrtzeit nicht zu knapp kalkulieren, vor allem wenn man umsteigen muss – denn auch wenn alles gut durchgeplant ist, kann es ***zu*** Verspätungen kommen.

I am wondering why **zu Verspätungen** was used and not **mit Verspätungen**?

> Dabei sollte man die Fahrtzeit nicht zu knapp kalkulieren, vor allem wenn man umsteigen muss – denn auch wenn alles gut durchgeplant ist, kann es ***mit*** Verspätungen kommen.

As I understand the meaning of **zu** it would not occur to me to use it here, like this. I have done a search for "zu Verspätungen" on DWDS and there are no hits, whereas a search for "mit Verspätungen" returns 19 hits. Is this a regionalism? Or is this just an error? Or is this a correct use of **zu** in some sense?

Comment: If you really searched for Verspäterungen instead of Verspätungen, that might explain the result

Comment: Thanks for the proofing. It was a typo in the question, but the searches were correctly done.

Comment: This "zu" is correct. BTW: I get 256000 hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"kommen" can carry a load of meanings in German, especially when used with prepositions. Not all of them can be found in the average dictionary.

"zu etwas kommen" can carry the meaning of "achieve something" or "reach a goal"

> Wenn du weiter so faul bist, wirst du nie zu etwas kommen

> Nur mit ehrlicher Arbeit kommt ein normaler Mensch niemals zu Reichtum

When used with an impersonate subject, the meaning changes to "something happens" or "something occurs" (much like the English "to come about")

> Im Falle von Naturkatastrophen kann es zu Verspätungen kommen

> Wenn die Batterien falsch eingesetzt werden, kann es zu Beschädigungen des Geräts kommen

[see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/kommen#d-1-8), Paragraph (8)]